# Blocking subprocess function in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, blocking

I had an asynchronous function being called like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def my_function(arg1, arg2):
    print 'Long process begins'

p = Process(target=my_function, args=(arg1, arg2,)).start()
```

How can I make this blocking? I need to finish the process before running the rest of the script.

Comment: Don't use multiprocess. Just call `my_function` in your script. It will "block".

Comment: I need to call it as a separate process because it interacts with PyQt objects that leak memory like crazy. Once the subprocess finished the memory is freed.

Comment: If you want to have a return value and error handling for this function, you can use the [processify decorator](https://gist.github.com/2311116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [p.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join)

> Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is
>   called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs.
>
> If timeout is None then there is no timeout.
>
> A process can be joined many times.
>
> A process cannot join itself because this would cause a deadlock. It
>   is an error to attempt to join a process before it has been started.